# database not populating in HTC One A9

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am getting some weird issue because it is coming only in HTC One A9.
It has Marshmallow 6.0.1 (may be because of this).
In all other devices(having lollipop as OS) the app is working as expected.
The app is developed on `Phonegap`.
Sqlite plugin : `cordova-plugin-sqlite`.

Some code snippet.

```
function OnDeviceReady (){

if(isOnline==true){
    try{
        app.initialize();
    }
    catch(exc){      
    }
}
else{
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "abc.db", createFromLocation: 1 });
    db.transaction(function (tx) {});
  }
}
```

database is in the www directory.
Not able to understand the error is because of Marshmallow 6.0.1 or because of sqlite plugin.
It always gives `Invalid database handle` error while prepopulating database.
Can anyone help  on this issue?

Comment: Hi I am having exactly the same problem with the new Sony Xperia Phone. With my older Android Phone it also works great, but with Android Marshmallow I get the same issue.

Could you find the solution to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes..found the solution...posting it...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `cordova-sqlite-ext` plugin for prepopulataion of database.
After then write the following

```
 var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: dbName, location:'default', createFromLocation: 1 });
  db.transaction(function (tx) {});
```

and in subsequent calls use the following --

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: dbName, location : 'default' });


        db.transaction(function (tx) {

            //Make the search query
            var _strSearchQuery = "where prod_id = '" + id + "' ";

            // Call the function to get the data from the local database and bind
            nsProductGetMSDS.RetriveProductDetails(tx, _strSearchQuery);

        }, CommonError, DoNothing);


    }
    else{
        alert(noInternetMessage);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I solved it by not using cordova-plugin-sqlite plugin anymore but the cordova-plugin-storage which is the new version of the first plugin.

Comment: check on HTC One A9 (Marshmallow 6.1) this device if possible...because i have also used storage plugin and dint worked on mentioned device...please crosscheck if possible...thanks

Comment: it did work! Also used 6.1 on on the xperia phone! Maybe the plugin was updated since you tested it!